# How can I find database entries since the last login of user in specific table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5

I am trying to find out a way in which I can calculate how many entries are added to specific table in database since the last login of the administrator of the website.

As I am creating the admin panel I need to find out how many subscription requests are arrived in the database table since the last login of administrator to the admin panel.

I just want to display the number of requests received?
I am using Laravel and mysql for database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table to store the Statics:

```
id | count | readed
```

Add a listener to your Subscription Request model, fired on every `Creation Event` (add it in a provider):

```
 SubscriptionRequest::created(function ($data) {
      //look for last statics record
     $last_static_unread  = Statics::where('readed',0)->first();
     //if there aren't any record is our first request since last login
      if(is_null($last_static_unread)){
        $last_static_unread = new Statics();
        $last_static_unread->count = 1;
        $last_static_unread->readed = 0;
        $last_static_unread->save();
      }else{
        $last_static_unread += 1;
        $last_static_unread->update();
      }
 });
```

Then in your admin panel get it and update it, for example in the controller to serve the main statics view or something:

```
public function getTotalRequestSinceLastVisit (){
    $last_statics = Statics::where('readed',0)->first()
    $total_requests = 0;
    if(!is_null($last_statics)){
       $total_requests = $last_statics->count;
       $last_statics->readed = 1;
       $last_statics->update();
    }
    return $total_requests;
}
```